# Scala tail recursion

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, tail-recursion

I have a function in scala that I wonder if it's possible to make into a tail recursive function.

```
def get_f(f: Int => Int, x: Int, y: Int): Int = x match {
  case 0 => y
  case _ => f(get_f(f, x - 1, y))
}
```

Comment: @pavel I don't get any errors, but I want to avoid stackoverflows in the future and make normal recursion into tail recursion

Answer (score 7):

I see that this function applies `f` function to result recursivly, `x` times. It's the same as applying it to `y`, `x` times. Also I suggest you to use `if else` instead of pattern matching.

```
@tailrec
def get_f(f: Int => Int, x: Int, y: Int): Int = 
    if(x == 0) y
    else get_f(f, x - 1, f(y))
```

Add `@tailrec` annotation to ensure that it is tail recursive

Answer (score 4):

It is possible but the way you've constructed it means you're going to have to use a Trampolined style to make it work:

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

def get_f(f: Int => Int, x: Int, y: Int): TailRec[Int] = x match {
  case 0 => done(y)
  case _ => tailcall(get_f(f, x - 1, y)).map(f)
}

val answer = get_f(_+1, 0, 24).result
```

You can read about TailRec [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/control/TailCalls$.html) or for more advanced study, this [paper](http://blog.higher-order.com/assets/trampolines.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with reducing number of parameters from your non-tailrec version to make it clear what it actually does:

```
def get_f(f: Int => Int, x: Int, y: Int) = {
  def get_f_impl(x: Int): Int = x match {
    case 0 => y
    case _ => f(get_f_impl(x - 1))
  }
  get_f_impl(x)
}
```

The idea is that actually you apply `f`-function x-times to initial value `y`. So, it becomes clear that you can do something like this in order to make it tail-recursive:

```
def get_f(f: Int => Int, x: Int, y: Int) = {
  @tailrec def get_f_impl(acc: Int, x: Int): Int = 
    if (x == 0) acc else get_f_impl(f(acc), x - 1) 
  get_f_impl(y, x)
}
```

REPL investigation:

Your original implementation:

```
scala> get_f(_ + 1, 4, 0)
res6: Int = 4
```

Your implementation (with params optimisation):

```
scala> get_f(_ + 1, 4, 0)
res0: Int = 4
```

Tailrec implementation:

```
scala> get_f(_ + 1, 4, 0)
res3: Int = 4
```

P.S. For more complex cases trampolines might fit: https://espinhogr.github.io/scala/2015/07/12/trampolines-in-scala.html

P.S.2 You can also try:

- [Scala - compose function n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346479/scala-compose-function-n-times)
  @adamw noticed that it will allocate n-sized list, so might not be very efficient
- `Endo.mulitply` in scalaz (your `f: Int => Int` is actually an endomorphism): https://stackoverflow.com/a/7530783/1809978 - not sure about efficiency

Comment: It's not really tail recursive, since `get_f_impl` calls `get_f`.

Comment: Sorry . I meant get_f_impl

Comment: I didn't check the code as I don't have scala REPL right now, but the idea is that function just applies `f` n times

Comment: I just checked it and it doesn't compile. `f(get_f_impl(...))` is not tail recursive.

Comment: You checked the wrong one - second example should compile. the first one is a simplification of original non-tail-recursive one

Comment: I think it's wrong, because you call `get_f_impl` with result of `f(x - 1)` not `x - 1`.

Comment: x is just a counter to apply a function `f` x times

Comment: Yes, but you turn this counter into a value after transforming it using `f`.

Comment: Corrected to pass accumulator too

Comment: `Function.chain` solution is not very efficient, since it requires to allocate a list of size x.

Comment: Your `Function.chain` solution can blow the stack because `compose` generates a function requiring 3 stack frames. Scala can not do tail call elimination outside the context of a tail recursive function.

Comment: wheaties, `Function.chain` will not blow the stack since it doesn't use `compose` internally, it's implemented using `foldRight` on input Seq: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/Function.scala#L24

Answer (score 2):

I'll add that you can achieve the same result by using `foldLeft` on `Range`, like this:

```scala
def get_f(f: Int => Int, x: Int, y: Int) =
  (0 until x).foldLeft(y)((acc, _) => f(acc))
```

Comment: That's not true, see: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L161 but `foldRight` creates a List of n elements internally (as it calls `foldLeft` on `reversed` iterator), so it's best to use `foldLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

In line with previous responses

```
 def get_f2( f: Int => Int, x: Int, y: Int) : Int = {
   def tail(y: Int, x: Int)(f: Int => Int) : Int = {
     x match {
       case 0 => y
       case _ => tail(f(y), x - 1)(f) : Int
     }
   }

   tail(y, x)(f)
 }
```